Slight delay when using transition method
I am using transition(from:to:duration:options:animations:completion:) method to move from one view controller to another. It happens fast but there is still a noticeable delay (about 1.5-5ms).
Here is my code:
func performTransition(to endController: UIViewController?) {
    
    guard let endController, self.activeController != endController else { return }
    
    let startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

    activeController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    addChild(endController)
    
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
        self.transition(from: self.activeController, to: endController, duration: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            
            endController.view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            }
            
        }) { [weak self] _ in

            self?.activeController.removeFromParent()
            endController.didMove(toParent: self)
            self?.activeController = endController

            let endTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            
            print("started at \(startTime)\nended at \(endTime)")
        }
    }

I added CACurrentMediaTime() to keep track of all the actions in the function, and noticed that delay occurs while executing a completion block. This is what it prints out:
started at 17011.142595500005
ended at 17011.178053125004

Figures differ, but you get the point. So my question is why is there a delay during the transition? I am still able to call any functions in other controllers while in my performTransition(to:) method and they get called immediately without delays, and the rest of the code keeps running. Even some UI elements get modified faster than the transition happens. I did add DispatchQueue block for some reason (I already forgot why, it's definitely there for a reason lol, nothing changes if removed). Just to mention, the completion block is not @escaping, so I assume it should run in the right sequence on main thread, but it acts like it runs on a concurrent thread. Is it just how UIKit works under the hood, or there is something I don't do or do wrong?

Remove asyncAfter: Since you're already performing the transition immediately, you may not need the asyncAfter call unless you have a specific reason for delaying. If you don't need any delay, you can perform the transition immediately without wrapping it in DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter.

@K.pen I tried it without asyncAfter, there is still a slight delay when completion block gets executed

Of course it got some delays here, what do you expect? Even between line 1 and line 2, there is still a delay in execution.

You say "...there is still a noticeable delay (about 1.5-2ms)." You can see a delay of 2 THOUSANDTHS of a second in the UI?!? You must have super-human perception. (I'm guessing that you mean that you are able to MEASURE a delay, not that you can see it in the interface. Delays of ≈1/100th of second are imperceptible. I think you are over-analyzing it.)

@DuncanC yes, that was the reason of this post. Transition followed by changes in UI elements are followed by a quick but noticeable flash. 120hz devices are able to make it noticeable. I recorded a video to calculate the delay in ms and it differs. Still the question why completion gets executed with a delay is not answered.

@sonle execution between lines 1 and 2 happens momentarily, figures are almost identical and don’t vary that much like in my example

If you need do it without delay, do it without transition. Still we doesn't know why you need DispatchQueue.main.async...
